# How to get Mac smooth scrolling to work on an element

Tags: javascript, css, html, overflow, smooth-scrolling

I've created a virtual-rendering implementation (similar to what you would find in the project SlickGrid). Everything seems to be working very well, with one problem: On Mac, smooth scrolling (the rubber-banding and fade-to-stop) doesn't work on my element when I add `overflow: auto`??

http://syntaqx.com/infiniload/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: On a Mac w/ a touchpad? if so, try adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to your element.

Comment: Nevermind that...fired up my macbook and that doesn't seem to do anything (unlike iOS): http://jsfiddle.net/EyLjB/

Comment: Thanks for trying though.. any other ideas on what I might be able to try? It seems weird that it only applies to elements with `overflow` and not the `window`. For example, try moving your mouse to the side of the page where the white elements aren't showing up.. things work just fine..

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only CSS property I know of which can impact scroll easing. You might have to use the `body` as the main container instead of `.window-container`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that brings along an entirely new set of bugs I have to deal with that are solved by using a `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS Librarys:
https://github.com/ftlabs/ftscroller

> FTScroller is a cross-browser Javascript/CSS library to allow touch,
>   mouse or scrollwheel scrolling within specified elements, with
>   pagination, snapping and bouncing support.